# Create subscription for OneDrive Business returns 403 forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to build and integration with OneDrive. Everything has worked well and I have been able to register my App, get a token, navigate the OneDrive items and download files.

I started creating subscriptions to receive notifications from OneDrive when user does something. This works without any problem when user signs in with their "personal account" but when they use "work or school" account I get the following error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The caller does not have permission to perform the action.]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ffaf7fae-e0b0-4cd8-b911-bac4c2fb290a",
      "date": "2019-09-18T00:18:40"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the call I make to create the subscription:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer [access_token]' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: graph.microsoft.com' \
  -d '        {
            "resource": "me/drive/root",
            "changeType": "updated",
            "clientState": "[email_Address]",
            "notificationUrl": "https://webhook_url",
            "expirationDateTime": "2019-09-19T04:43:47.6099364+00:00"
        }'
```

The user has `Files.ReadWrite.All` permission which based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions) should be enough.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#files-permissions) Admin Consent is no required for delegated permissions

Comment: Is the user able to view their OneDrive in a browser?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur yes of course they can. As mentioned above I can call the API without the problem and even download files. The problem here is creating subscriptions.

Comment: For future reference, there have been issues in the past with OD not being properly provisioned and the tell-tale symptom was the inability to open the OD UI. So no, it isn't always safe to assume "of course they can".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this same problem. The only difference is I am trying to setup a `driveItem` subscription on a business OneDrive path `/users/<id>/drive/root` but getting the same error as you on the response.

So, using the same access token, I did a `GET /v1.0/users/<id>/drive/root` and fetched the `driveId` of the parent from the response. Then I attempted to create the subscription at `/drives/<driveId>/root` and it worked. All requests were using the same access token and the previous way used to work for months.

So you might try doing a GET for your `/me/drive/root` and see if you can set it up with the `driveId`.

As a bonus, the subscription is now sending web-hooks like I expect.

Comment: Thanks @eric-olson! `/drives/<driveId>/root` works for both personal and business drives.

Comment: Also worked for me this is actually an breaking change that was added recently to the graph api. For me I used /drives/<userId>/root because the ID returned via GET to the /users/<userId>/drive/root endpoint is not a valid driveId

Comment: `/users/<userId>/drive/root` isn't a valid `drive` Id because it isn't a drive, it's a folder within a drive. If you call `/me/drive` the `id` is `drive` identifier. If you call `/me/drive/root/` the `id` is the `driveItem` identified. You'll find the `drive` identifier under the `parentReference.driveId` property.

Comment: Might be off topic but do you know if One Drive still does not allow subscription to a single item in a drive?

Comment: anyone getting empty  resourceData using this approach?

Comment: I am getting empty resourceData

Comment: Thanks @eric-olsen, but it's weird that Microsoft doesn't correct the documentation, we can clearly see here:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph- rest-1.0), that `/users/<userId>/drive/root` should work